# Export a Quick Model from Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uml

I was looking for a quick way to generate UML like documentation for my project when I stumbled across the Quick Model menu item in Xcode. I was wondering if there were a way to export these diagrams in a non-platform-specific file format like png or pdf? Basically I want to take some quick visual diagrams (illustrating component relationships) of some of the major classes in our project to management. Does anyone know of an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File > Print, and choose Save to PDF from the gear menu in the Print dialog. Works in nearly every Mac OS X app.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Does anybody know how to get this on one page? I tried to set `Pages per Sheet` to 16 and `Destination Paper Size` to A3 and experienced the `Save preset bug`. However, I still have the document name, time and page enumeration on each page. Does somebody know how to get rid off it? Also there is an option `Save PDF to iPhoto` but I don't have currently iPhoto installed and I also can't find it on my recovery disk ... I think making a screenshot and manually assembly the pictures together with filtering and hiding is the best option I have.

Comment: More about the class modelling:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XCodeDesignTools/Articles/xdtDesignTools.html

More about filtering and hiding:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XCodeDesignTools/Articles/xdtDiagramView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006859-SW8

Answer (score 0):

@testing GraphicConverter allows you to open PDF's or files saved to iPhoto and then converted to PNG and crop them with precision to then rejoin in a bigger file. It's quite tedious but works. OmniGraffle should have a CoreData importer but it's not in the Standard version.